# Need help with: show that $R$ is also a Euclidean domain under the function $\theta$ given by $\theta(r)=\delta(r)+k.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, euclidean-domain

*Background:*

**Definition:**  An integral domain $R$ is a Euclidean domain if there is a function $\delta$ from the nonzero elements of $R$ to the nonnegative integers with these properties;

*(i)*  If $a$ and $b$ are nonzero elements of $R,$ then $\delta(a)\leq \delta(ab).$

*(ii)*  If $a,b\in R$ and $b\neq 0_R,$ then there exist $q,r\in R$ such that $a=bq+r$ and either $r=0_R$ or $\delta(r) < \delta(b).$

**Exercise 13 a:**  Let $R$ be a Eucidean domain with function $\delta$ and let $k$ be a positive integer.

*(a)*  Show that $R$ is also a Euclidean domain under the function $\theta$ given by $\theta(r)=\delta(r)+k.$

> *Proof:* It is easy to check that $\theta(ab)=\delta(ab)+k\leq \delta(a)\delta(b)+k\leq(\delta(a)+k)(\delta(b)+k)=\theta(ab)$.  Now suppose $a=bq+r$ where $0\leq r<|b|$. where either $r=0$ or $\delta(r)<\delta(b)$.  In the case $r\neq 0$ check $\theta(a)=\delta(a)+k\leq \delta(b)+k=\theta(b)$.

*Questions:*

For exercise 13a) above, to show *(i)* of the definition of Euclidean domain.  I at first did the following;

Let $a,b\in R$ and let $k$ be a fixed integer. with $a<b$, $a<ab$, $\delta(a)+k<\delta(b)+k$, and $\delta(a)+k<\delta(ab)+k$.  Then $\theta(a)=\delta(a)+k<\delta(ab)+k=\theta(ab)$.  I also know that $\delta(a)\delta(b)\leq \delta(a)(\delta(b)+k)\leq (\delta(a)+k)(\delta(b)+k)=\theta(a)\theta(b)$.

In the solution above for the exercise above for showing *(i)* of defintion for Euclidean domain, part of it says: $\theta(ab)=\delta(ab)+k\leq \delta(a)\delta(b)+k\leq (\delta(a)+k)(\delta(b)+k)=\theta(a)\theta(b)$.   I don't understand how $\delta(ab)+k\leq \delta(a)\delta(b)+k$
is valid when it has not know shown $\delta(ab)\leq \delta(a)\delta(b)$.  I am not sure if there is a typo in the step: $\delta(a)\delta(b)+k\leq (\delta(a)+k)(\delta(b)+k)$.  It seems it should be $\delta(a)(\delta(b)+k)$ instead of $\delta(a)\delta(b)+k$.  Also, why is showing $\theta(ab)=\theta(a)\theta(b)$ needed?

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1) Your $a<b,a<ab$ makes no sense (there is no ordering on $R$). 2) "$\delta(a)+k<\delta(b)+k$" has no reason to hold. 3) Your proof that $\theta(a)\le\theta(ab)$ will be fine if you replace every $<$ by $\le$. 4) The solution you were given is wrong. There is no reason for $\delta(ab)\le\delta(a)\delta(b)$ nor $\theta(ab)\le\theta(a)\theta(b)$ to hold (think of $\delta$ = the polynomial degree, and $a,b$= polynomials of degree 1)

Comment: Follow up. To summarize: your proof that $\theta$ satisfies (i) is fine, whereas the "proof" you were given makes no sense. As for (ii), the (very simple) "check" in the proof you were given is sufficient.

Comment: @AnneBauval Condition $(i)$ for definition of Euclidean domain, if I can only prove that $\theta(a)<\theta(ab)$ and not $\theta(a)\leq \theta(ab)$, is that still enough to show that condition $(i)$ is satisfied?  Also from your comments, I can dispense with the $\theta(ab)=\theta(a)\theta(b),$ since those steps are invalid.  I deleted my other post.

Comment: The question is valid, the given solution is incorrect, $\theta(a)<\theta(ab)$ would be sufficient but is wrong (think of $b=1$), you can only prove $\theta(a)\le\theta(ab)$. You don't have to (and anyway cannot) prove $\theta(ab)=\theta(a)\theta(b)$.

Comment: @AnneBauval one last thing, so in general, for condition $(i)$ of Euclidean domain.  To show a ring $R$ that satisfies it with a fiven function $f$ ,if I can't show that $f(a)=f(ab)$ and can only show that $f(a)<f(ab)$ holds for $a,b\in R,$  that would be sufficient.  Also, I don't need to show that the $f$ function satisfies $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)?$

Comment: Again: you cannot show that $f(a)<f(ab)$ (think of $b=1$), you can only show that $f(a)\le f(ab)$. And you can see yourself that conditions (i) and (ii) include nothing like multiplicativity of $f$.

Comment: @AnneBauval ah kk.  Thank you. thank you.